# ArcMap calculate distance (from and to) from a points shape to the lines shape table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-join, linear-referencing

I am trying to calculate the **From** and **To** fields in the line table. 
I have got a points shape and i have got a line shape. ( see for example the figure bellow.)
The points( in red ) intersect with lines. 
My plan is to get the distance from points for the begin and end of the each line segment. I have tried spatialjoin but it gives only the distance but not giving +/- form the points location. I need to update each line with the 'ID'of the point + begin and end distance from that 'ID'point ( see the figure : in table i have updated 2 records manually). I think i am clear about what i want to do. 
What i have done is just measured the distance with measuring tool and updated the fields manually.
I have more than 500 line segemnts.
I think there must be a better way than this.
I am working with ArcMap 10.6

figure ( it's an example) :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might solve it.

Run [Feature Vertices To Points](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) with the following parameters: in_features: your lines, out_featureclass: path to a fc with name like 'pts_start', point_location: 'START'

Run [Generate Near Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm#L_) in_features: your points, and near_features 'pts_end', out_table to 'pts_end_dist'

I think all the data you need to get the END point data is spread across the 4 datasets.  Then it's a matter of joining the data (with the [Add Join](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-join.htm) tool or the layer context menu) and running a [Calculate Field](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm) to create a single value and put it into your field named 'TO'.

If that works, repeat for the FROM value.

Comment: Thanks for trying to solve the issue. I tried your solution but its not producing the desired results to me. Genearate Near Table gives the distances(start_pts and end_pts) but not gives the + or - from the points ( red in figure ). For example for start_pts line 4 ( green line in figure ), i am getting distance from point "ZCA2". But instead i want to get from "ZBA1" .